# javascript regex to find string at nth line from a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find a specific string from a specific line using javascript regex.  Help me to find out.

```
Salary period 2019-6-M
Deductions
Along fin Robert(Netherlands)
s.v
Mr. E.P.  Benjamin
San Marco 25
German
```

from the above string, I need to find **Benjamin**. The **Deductions** string is constant, so what I have tried is 
    (?<=Deductions)\n*?(\w+\s*) to find from where line start and  ^[^\n]+\n(.+)+\n(.+)+\n(.+) to find **Benjamin**. but don't know to merge both and get it.

Answers are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post more examples, or describe the common pattern for your inputs? It's not clear what the general solution would be just from this

Comment: Please check here. https://regex101.com/r/MEvFpI/4.

Comment: This will capture Benjamin in group 1 but is the structure and the amount of lines always the same? Is there any other logic? `\bDeductions(?:\n.*){2}\n.* (\S+)$`  https://regex101.com/r/GQe8RK/1

Comment: This may work for you if `n=3`: https://regex101.com/r/lbHgFC/1

Comment: @anubhava. n is 3 here, I meant from Deductions 3rd line.

Comment: In that case my earlier suggested regex should work for you.

Comment: In Windows a newline is actually \r\n, not just \n ! Use \s*? to match both.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic regex based on your start string and amount of lines like this:

```js
var input = `Salary period 2019-6-M
Deductions
Along fin Robert(Netherlands)
s.v
Mr. E.P.  Benjamin
San Marco 25
German `;

function find(text, from, lines, text_find) {
  var regex = new RegExp(from + '.*?\n(?:.*?\n){' + lines + '}.*?(' + text_find + ')');
  var match = text.match(regex);
  if (match) return match[1];
  return null;
}
console.log(find(input, 'Deductions', 2, 'Benjamin'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this :

```
(?<=Deductions)(?:.*\n){3}?.* (\w+)\n
```

does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a positive lookbehind, you could match Deductions followed by  repeating 2 times matching the whole string.

In the third string, match until the end and capture the last "word" in a group matching 1+ times a non whitespace char.

```
\bDeductions(?:\n.*){2}\n.* (\S+)$
```

- `\bDeductions` Word boundary, match Deductions
- `(?:\n.*){2}` Repeat 2 times a newline and 0+ chars except newline until the end of the string
- `\n.* (\S+)` Match newline, 0+ char except newline. Then match a space and capture 1+ times a non whitespace char in group 1.
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OlVuEt/1)

```js
const regex = /\bDeductions(?:\n.*){2}\n.* (\S+)$/m;
const str = `Salary period 2019-6-M
Deductions
Along fin Robert(Netherlands)
s.v
Mr. E.P.  Benjamin
San Marco 25
German `;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```